# Flutter + Sql: Unexpected character ( if barcode starts with '0...')

Tags: sql, flutter, dart

I have an old error with Table field ProductBarcode (even if it's a nvarchar type field). When I scan the Barcode and it starts with '0' (zero) I get Unexpected Character. I think it's caused because of the Json. I'm using sql_conn package to fetch data. Also I get error if barcode starts with "-" for example I got products that have this barcode: "-1288865", "-01194070"

Function read():

```js
Future<List?> read(String query) async {
  var result;
  await _readLock.synchronized(() async {
    result = await SqlConn.readData(query);
  });
  
  List list = jsonDecode(result) as List;
  return list;
}
```

sql request to fetch data based on parameters (ProductStation i choose, and BarCode I scan - once I scan it does the sql request):

```js
Expanded(
                child: FutureBuilder<List?>(
                    future: read("SELECT Id, OrderID, RowID, ProductCode, ProductAdress+' ' ProductAdress, REPLACE(REPLACE(ProductName, '\"', ''''), '\t', ' ') AS ProductName, CAST(NeedCount AS VARCHAR) AS NeedCount, ProductSeriesDescr+' ' ProductSeriesDescr, ScanCount, ScanPost, ProductSeriesCount+' ' ProductSeriesCount, ProductExpirationDate, CAST(ProductBarCode AS VARCHAR) AS ProductBarCode FROM ScanRest WHERE ProductStation = '${widget.nrStatie}' AND BoxID = '$cutieScan' and OrderDate = CONVERT(date, GETDATE()) ORDER BY Id ASC"),
                    builder: (context, snapshot) {
                      switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
                        case ConnectionState.waiting:
                          return const Text('Loading....');
                        default:
                          if (snapshot.hasError) {
                            debugPrint("call error ${snapshot.error}"); //"call error = ${snapshot.error}"  
                            return Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
                          }
                          debugPrint('${snapshot.data}'); // "call success = ${snapshot.data}"
                          List data = snapshot.data ?? [];
                          if (snapshot.data!.isEmpty) {
                            return Visibility(
                                visible: !vizibil,
                                child: Column(children: [
                                  const Text('Barcode gresit sau statie goala'),
                                  IconButton(
                                      onPressed: () {
                                        Navigator.push(context,
                                          MaterialPageRoute(
                                            builder: (context) => widget));
                                      },
                                      icon: const Icon(Icons.replay_outlined)),
                                ]));
                          }
                          
                          for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                            if (data[i]['ProductBarCode'] is String) {
                              data[i]['ProductBarCode'] = data[i]['ProductBarCode'].replaceAll('0', 'A');
                            }
                          }


                          int index = 0;
                          for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                            if (int.parse(data[i]['NeedCount'].toString()) - int.parse(data[i]['ScanCount'].toString()) == 0 || data[i]['ScanPost'] == 1) {
                              if (index == i) {
                                index++;
                              }
                            }
                            if (index == data.length) {
                              WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
                                if(_counter != 0){
                                  notificationAlert(context, 'Scanat: $_counter', const Color.fromARGB(255, 255, 218, 185), Colors.black);
                                }
                                Navigator.push(
                                  context,
                                  MaterialPageRoute(
                                    builder: (context) => dita_lista(
                                      nrStatie: widget.nrStatie,
                                      cutieScan: cutieScan,
                                      userName: widget.userName,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                );
                              });
                            }
                          }
```

Im ready to provide additional information. Don't understand what Is causing the error.

Comment: Because "0.." and "-..." are in first position. I tryied: SUBSTRING(ProductBarCode, 2, LEN(ProductBarCode)) as ProductBarCode. It will substract first character, it's not a quite good handle of error, but it works for now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in JSON as I said, I found the solution that worked for me and here is what I modified in function read:

```js
Future<List?> read(String query) async {
  var result;
  await _readLock.synchronized(() async {
    result = await SqlConn.readData(query);
  });

  result = result.replaceAllMapped(
      RegExp(r'"ProductBarCode":(-?\d+)'),
      (match) => '"ProductBarCode":"${match.group(1)}"');

  List list = json.decode(result) as List;

  return list;
}
```